# How to establish a LAN connection with 1 modem, 1 wireless modem, and 1 wireless router?

Tags: networking, home-networking, lan, media-server

So here's the situation:

I've got my desktop computer downstairs which is connected directly into my new wireless modem that my ISP gave me.

Upstairs, I have my TV and my PS3 which is connected directly into my old (non-wireless) modem which my ISP conveniently let me keep so that I could have a connection upstairs.

I also have a wireless router which I'm no longer using because I have the wireless modem now.

I'd like to stream videos from my computer to my PS3 (via PS3 media player), but I don't know how to establish a LAN connection.

Is this possible? How? Running a cable from downstairs to upstairs is not an option.

If I have to do it wirelessly, how should I set it up? I'd like my PS3 and PC both to remain wired to the internet directly. I can move the 3 modems/routers around where-ever though.

**Edit:** I can probably find one more (maybe 2) wireless router lying around if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Forget the modem with the tv/ps3, that will do you no good. You'll want to create a wireless bridge with you old wireless router (may require alternate firmware like ddwrt or openwrt). This will bridge the devices upstairs with the network downstairs. The only way to have the ps3 wired is to actually run a cable between the two points.